# file_get_contents() working for some sites but not another

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, external, file-get-contents

I have 3 websites sitting on the same webserver. I am using file_get_contents from my WAMP localhost to do some funky coding from these 3 wordpress sites but the function does not work on 1 of the 3, it returns false which means it can't get anything. But crazily when accessed directly the url works. Here is the output of get_headers() if that helps at all, note the first one is different. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 04:37:21 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => X-Pingback: http://armidaleplumber.com.au/wp/xmlrpc.php
    [6] => Link: ; rel=shortlink
    [7] => Set-Cookie: nf_wp_session=812a895bc4008d398bf10c61bbdc5dc7%7C%7C1439570241%7C%7C1439568441; expires=Fri, 14-Aug-2015 16:37:21 GMT; path=/
    [8] => X-Powered-By: PleskLin
)


Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 04:37:22 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [6] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    [7] => Pragma: no-cache
    [8] => X-Pingback: http://armidalebuilder.com.au/wp/xmlrpc.php
    [9] => Link: ; rel=shortlink
    [10] => Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=q515dll808qtabnr1v6s4a1sn1; path=/
    [11] => X-Powered-By: PleskLin
)


Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 04:37:23 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [6] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    [7] => Pragma: no-cache
    [8] => X-Pingback: http://armidaleelectrician.com.au/wp/xmlrpc.php
    [9] => Link: ; rel=shortlink
    [10] => Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0m9afhknr7c0ijiso51j6264s7; path=/
    [11] => X-Powered-By: PleskLin
)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the non-working URL to your question? Maybe there is a space in it so that you have to `urlencode` it first. (see the note in [file_get_contents documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php))

Comment: there is a setting allow url fopen it may blocked. you have to use curl library to access urls `if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {   // lucky me... } ` if you lucky it's works

Comment: Don't worry, I have decided to use CURL instead, it works great every time. thanks for you help!